# Set CopyingRowClipboardContent event dynamically for all DataGrids

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to be able to copy a cell instead of a row when I hit Ctrl + C in a DataGrid, and I found that I can do this using the event CopyingRowClipboardContent and the handler :

```
Private Sub DataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs)
    Dim currentCell = e.ClipboardRowContent(dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear()
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Add(currentCell)
End Sub
```

I would like to assign this behavior globally to any DataGrid created during runtime (instead of going back to my code and adding the handler to all the DataGrid one by one).

I tried adding the following line into my `<Window.Resources>` code :

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <EventSetter Event="CopyingRowClipboardContent" Handler="Datagrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent" />
</Style>
```

But I get an error saying that CopyingRowClipboardContent must be a RoutedEvent event.

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Did you get it working somehow?

Comment: @RafaGomez Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

I've read again your question after commenting, and I think we are not looking for the same...

If you just  want to be able to select ONE cell instead of entire row then I think you can go with

```xml
<Style x:Key="DataGridCustomStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <!--Copy only selected content without header-->
    <Setter Property="ClipboardCopyMode" Value="ExcludeHeader" />
    <!--Able to select many cells-->
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
    <!--Able to select cells or entire row/column-->
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="CellOrRowHeader" />
</Style>
```

So this way if user has just one cell selected and press Ctrl+C only the selected cell content will be pasted to clipboard.